# MVC 6 - cannot pass multiple JSON parameters to a controller anymore

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have recently been working to use the new `ASP.NET 5` system, and Microsoft's `ASP.NET MVC 6`, but I am finding a few very key problems that are preventing me from going forward; Most notably is that I cannot seem to pass multiple `JSON` parameters through a controller method anymore.

For example, I have the following controller method;

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("edit/profile")]
public void Attribute([FromBody]Models.Profile model, bool editing) {
    // ...
    // model always comes in null
    // editing always comes in default (false)
}
```

I am attempting to pass data to this controller using `$.ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/edit/profile',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ model: _this.model, editing: true })
});
```

But no matter what I do, the parameters always come in `null` on the controller. I have tried various things, and if I ignore the `({ model : _this.model ... })` part and just pass in only ONE parameter, it comes through as expected `data: JSON.stringify(_this.model)`

The model looks like this; (obviously not the final model, just a dummy while I work on this problem)

```
_this.model = {
    Id: null,
    Name: null
    Text: null
};
```

And it corresponds to this `C#` class;

```
namespace Models {
    public class Profile {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I just cannot figure it out for the life of me. This worked fine on `MVC 5`, but since upgrading it is just completely defunct.

I am also using **`jQuery 2.1.4`**

Comment: try removing `JSON.stringify` and have a plain object as data: `data: { model: _this.model, editing: true }`

Comment: also try adding `[FromBody]` to `editing`

Comment: I've attempted both of those, and neither work.

Comment: any updates on this, today I lost 4 hours trying any combination to get multiple parameters on .Net Core 1.1. Is there any logical why we cant post whit ajax and json as it was smoothly in MVC 5?. I have not fund any bug trace or logic explanation why this is not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar problem. I have solved it by using a separate class for data.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("edit/profile")]
public void Attribute([FromBody] ProfileData data)
{
    var model = data.Model;
    var editing = data.Editing;
}

public class ProfileData
{
    public Models.Profile Model { get; set; }
    public bool Editing { get; set; }
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/edit/profile',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { data: { Model: _this.model, Editing: true } }
});
```

Comment: I can confirm that this worked; But why? Why is this behavior different between MVC 5 and 6? Is there any way to fix it? At first glance, I assume the issue is because the `JSON` going to the controller actually has two root level objects, and it can't map them - but that seems so bizarre.

Comment: It is not different - this is how it works in MVC 5 as well. I prepared my answer using MVC 5.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/edit/profile',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { model: JSON.stringify(_this.model), editing: true }
});
```

OR

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/edit/profile',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { model: _this.model, editing: true }
});
```

Either should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, unfortunately neither of those work. I continue to get `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class with `Profile Model` and `bool Editing` properties. Then, use it as a parameter in your API method with `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[Route("api/profile/edit")]
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] ProfileViewModel content)
{

}

public class ProfileViewModel
{
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }

    public bool Editing { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/profile/edit',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ profile: { name: 'Test' }, editing: true })
});
```

In Angular (you use it, as you mentioned in comments), you could use:

```
$http.post('api/profile/edit', { profile: { name: 'Test' }, editing: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this query and remove the `FromBody` attribute, it should work.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/edit/profile',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { model: _this.model, editing: true }
});


[HttpPost]
[Route("edit/profile")]
public void Attribute(Models.Profile model, bool editing) {

}
```

Comment: No, it does not. I just get a jQuery error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined`

Comment: @Ciel Interesting, but at least another error. I'm not sure what causes it, but if you resolve it it should work on ASP.NET side. This is exactly the way it works in my application.

Comment: @Ciel are you sure that `_this` is not `undefined`?

Comment: @Ciel where does the error occur? In the $.ajax call?

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure the problem there is because I am using `angular`, and the `model` is attached to the scope. So when it tries to send that model, there is a ton of metadata attached as well. I wonder if there is a way to strip all of that out.

Comment: @Ciel I dont know angular, so I cant help you in that regard, sry. But the quesiton I'd ask is, why doesnt the error occur in your version of the request?

Comment: If you are using angular, why do you use `ajax` method from jQuery? There is `$http` service in angular to handle ajax requests.

Comment: I'm more familiar with `$.ajax` and haven't fully added all the angular stuff in. But I've tried both, I get the same result.

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Angular (besides directives) is bad idea and eventually will give you a lot of headache. Nonetheless, the problem is with you API method - POST should only have one parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute.

Comment: @Ciel have you tried it using `$http` from angular? Maybe this will not result in JavaScript errors

Answer (score 0):

The json objct in js file:

```
var PeopleJson = {
        Name: "Volfgam"
}
```

To send for the controller use $.post() not $.ajax:

```
$.post("/api/people", PeopleJson)
        .done(function (response) {
            that.IsLoading(false);
            alert(response);
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            that.IsLoading(false);
            alert(error.statusText);
        });
```

Your controller, is very simples:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPeople(Teste PeopleJson)
{
   return Json(PeopleJson);
}
```

Your class:

```
   public class Teste
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
```

**I hope this helps.**